# JS If/Then to Remove NULL Value

Tags: javascript, filter, null

I have a very simple JS script that is embedded into an email.  The goal is to autopopulate the salutation of the email and is as follows.

```
if (Contact.Field("firstname") == "NULL") {
    document.write(Contact.Field("custname"));
} else if (Contact.Field("firstname") == "") {
    document.write(Contact.Field("lastname")"Household");
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the script will still autopopulate the NULL value in the email instead of switching to the "custname" field when it runs.  I'm sure this is due to user error, but if anyone could help steer me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: This is, I believe a typo. `"NULL"` should be `NULL` (without the quotes).

Comment: hello null should be without the quotes and i like it to use strict checking with 3 equal to's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `"NULL"` in the if statement, where you should have used `null` (without quotes, and in lowercase letters.) on it's own, like this:

```
if (Contact.Field("firstname") == null) {
    document.write(Contact.Field("custname"));
} else if (Contact.Field("firstname") == "") {
    document.write(Contact.Field("lastname")"Household");
}
```

Using `"NULL"` would check if the text in `Contact.Field("custname")` was the string "NULL", rather than checking if it has no content.

As to whether to use `==` or `===`, you can find an answer here: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Hello, i doubt NULL exists in JS. It should be in small caps - null.

Comment: @ashley Yes, I believe you are right. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.